# modules showing undefined in console upon bundling them with browserify

Tags: javascript, jquery, browserify

I am new to browserify and trying to understand it before I shift my project to it.

I went through the docs and understood how to use it, I am trying to include some more dependencies but upon usage, they are being stated not defined!

Here are my files:

main.js

```
window.jQuery = $ = require("jquery");
require('bootstrap');
require("jquery-confirm");
require("html2canvas");
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "html2canvas": "^0.5.0-beta4",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-confirm": "^3.3.2",
    "jshint": "^2.9.5",
    "qrcodejs": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Html2canvas, jshint and qrcode all are being shown undefined when I try to access these through browser console but jquery-confirm seems to work fine.

Let me know where I am wrong on this.

-Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're loading them as modules. The whole point of being able to use a bundling system such as Browserify is so you don't *have* to have global variables.

If you check the return value from one of those return calls, you'll see.

Example:

```
var html2canvas= require('html2canvas');
console.log(html2canvas);
```

If you would like to make them global (and you should really caution against doing this) then you can attach them to the `window` object.

```
window.html2canvas = require('html2canvas');
```

But I thoroughly want to suggest that you *don't* make things global unless you have to. For example, you can use jQuery in any of your files just by doing this at the start:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```